# Back propagation through time, understanding

Tags: artificial-intelligence, recurrent-neural-network

```
Back_Propagation_Through_Time(a, y)   // a[t] is the input at time t. y[t] is the output
Unfold the network to contain k instances of f
do until stopping criteria is met:
    x = the zero-magnitude vector;// x is the current context
    for t from 0 to n - 1         // t is time. n is the length of the training sequence
        Set the network inputs to x, a[t], a[t+1], ..., a[t+k-1]
        p = forward-propagate the inputs over the whole unfolded network
        e = y[t+k] - p;           // error = target - prediction
        Back-propagate the error, e, back across the whole unfolded network
        Update all the weights in the network
        Average the weights in each instance of f together, so that each f is identical
        x = f(x);                 // compute the context for the next time-step
```

Hey,

I don't understand the concept of the algorithm above, are we creating k instances of a neural network f (k copies) and then passing a[t] as input and x as input and what is x = f(x)?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

> are we creating k instances of a neural network

Kind of. In a recurrent neural network the output of the network for some input x<sub>i</sub> depends on each of the x<sub>i-j</sub> that came before it. So when you call the network with an input of length k, the network can effectively be "unfolded" into k networks, each feeding into each other sequentially.

After unfolding, the recurrent neural network looks a lot like a traditional neural network with hidden layers. We can use the backpropagation algorithm to then assign error and update our weights.

> what is x = f(x)?

The 'context' or `x` is like the 'memory' of the neural network. It's like time-varying output depending on which iteration of the recurrent network you're in. It's initialized to all zeros at the start because there is no memory. We compute it with `x = f(x)` because the output of a previous layer forms part of the input for the next layer (the other part being a[t<sub>i</sub>])